# Android - Keep original List Array when distinct it ? Java

Tags: java, android

I need to have original list of data and changed list of data **when I distinct it**.

For exmaple :

```
List<Marketing_Points> userPointList = new ArrayList<>();
userPointList  = /*Add a list of data */
Set<Marketing_Points> distinct = new HashSet<>();
distinct.addAll(userPointList);
userPointList.clear();
userPointList.addAll(distinct);
```

I need to original list and changed list now but I have just changed list of data.What can I do for keep original list?

My `android studio` is `(2.1.2)` and in my `build.gradle(Module.app)`  I am using :

```
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}
```

And my `JDK` is :

[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'distinct it'

Comment: add elements to distinct, including duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply create a `dummy list` and `add all elements of original list to it` and then you can use either of them to create a distinct list(though should use dummy list).

although Set doesn't allow duplicate value so if you have any duplicate value in list then it won't be added to Set(i guess u know this ) so keep a copy of original list to use later

Comment: Can I set a query (for example select query) on my list array ?I don't like increase my source code .

Comment: you can remove the code `userPointList.clear();` to keep the original data in your list and use data inside set for distinct data